# Partially update page on fileupload in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload

I have read that ajax fileupload is not possible. But I want to upload a file from my webpage, and retain the values of other fields.

In other words I want to update only some parts of page on fileupload, if ajax file upload is not possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's posible, you can either use library like http://www.uploadify.com/
or submit a form with target to a hidden iframe in your page, on server side you should print a js code to call a handle function in you current page
like this
window.top.handlefunction()

Answer (score 0):

Ajax file upload is possible. It just depends on your solution.

Look at this website for a basic form solution. Main idea is that you create  a form on a page, put file inputs in it etc. but set it's frame to a hidden iframe on a page, so that once the form submits, the page reload occurs in in the fame.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

If you only have to support modern browsers (HTML5 enhanced), you can use FormData and submit that over XHR.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData